# Cannot open QuickBooks error from IIS

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We have a WCF service that needs to insert data into QuickBooks.  We have already written code that can successfully insert data via the QB API (SDK).  If we run this code directly through a testing console application, everything works fine.  However, if we invoke this code from the WCF code, we get errors (lots of errors :) ).  So, we now use a Process() object in our WCF code that executes the .exe that inserts data into QB.  The problem is that we receive the following error when starting the .exe from the WCF service:  "Could not start QuickBooks".  Again, if we launch the .exe console application directly, all of the code works.  It appears that the way we invoke the Process() and p.StartInfo properties is important here but we aren't sure what we need to set in order to get past this error.  Has anyone else had success calling an .exe from IIS which in turn contains QB API code to integrate with that system?  Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code you use to call the executable. Without that it will be very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Hi eeichler , we are also facing same problem.. did you get any answer can you please share with me ....it will help me a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known, well documented limitation of how QuickBooks and the QuickBooks SDK works.

The QuickBooks SDK *requires* that you call it from within a Windows GUI session. If a Windows GUI isn't available (e.g. you're calling it from within a Windows service, IIS, etc.) then it *will not work*.

You should probably be using the Web Connector, not COM objects from within IIS.

Comment: Hi Keith palmer-consolibyt , i have fallow your way of explanation . it's working . But i don't want open WEb connector for every time . is there any chance to passing parametrs to web connector to open scilently please help me...

Comment: No, there isn't. You have to open it.